# Linq add dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to add a dynamic where clause to my linq code. But I am getting the following error. Other samples gives the same code but they are working fine so im not sure if i missed something.

```
var toBeReturn = db.estimate.ToList();
if(sname != null)
{
    toBeReturn =  toBeReturn.Where(x => x.estimate_status == sname);
}
```

Error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Help please

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote basic queries, if you don't know answer or consider a question not worth to answer, ignore it, but why dissuade new people needing help.

Comment: I am also surprised that a perfectly valid question showing the OPs efforts, expected and actual results would get downvoted.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov While I didn't downvote the question, the questioner seems to have ignored the error he received. We are lucky that C# (compared to, for example templated C++) gives "clear" errors. Here the error was quite. But this clearness is wasted if a person doesn't even try to read and comprehend the message.

Comment: before you Judge the OP, please keep in mind that people here ask basic question so that they can apply it to more complex problem.

and if you read my reply I have been trouble shooting this error. Thats why I came here to get an outside perspective on what i missed.

So really? @xanatos really?

Comment: While the error message might seem obvious for an experienced C# developer, that might not be the case for everyone. When you say *We are lucky that C# (compared to, for example templated C++) gives "clear" errors* I suppose that this is your perspective. But what do you think an experienced C++ developer might say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to call `.ToList()` at the end in order to get a `List<T>` which is the type of the `toBeReturn` variable:

```
toBeReturn =  toBeReturn.Where(x => x.estimate_status == sname).ToList();
```

Also I would recommend you inverting your logic so that you filter the results on the SQL server if the `sname` variable has value. In your current implementation, you are fetching all records from the table and then filter them in-memory which is not the most efficient approach.

```
var toBeReturn = (sname != null) 
    ? db.estimate.Where(x => x.estimate_status == sname).ToList()
    : db.estimate.ToList();
```